# How to upgrade magento 2.1.6 to 2.1.9?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I want to upgrade magento 2.1.6 to 2.1.9 ?How to upgrate it?

Bellow admin site display message .

> Important Magento Open Source 2.1.9 and 2.0.16 Security Enhancements –
>   9/14/2017
>
> Magento Open Source 2.1.9 and 2.0.16 include critical security
>   enhancements and address the September 1 changes to USPS shipping.
>   Please update your s ite as soon as possible. More information is
>   available in the release notes:

Comment: step by step guide https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-2-x-to-latest-version/

Comment: How long does it take to upgrade or install component
I have magento 2.1.7 Trying to install components one by one and then upgrade system It’s just saying update is in progress Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1: Access Your Server via SSH**

You need to connect your server via SSH.

**Step 2: Navigate to the Magento 2 Root Directory**

Once your SSH connection is up, you will need to move to your target application folder. In that application folder, you will find the public_html folder which is the root directory of Magento 2.

**Step 3: Upgrade Commands**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.9 --no-update
```

Then execute this all commands

```
 composer update
 rm -rf var/di var/generation
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento cache:flush
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Ok @David. Happy to helping :) Happy Coding :) You can give upvote to answer. So, It will useful to others.

Comment: I ran the above commands composer was installed without any error but my site crashed with internal server error 500 .

Answer (score 3):

Below are the commands how to upgrade it .

> **composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.9 --no-update (pass required update version number)**
>
> - composer update
> - rm -rf var/di var/generation
> - php bin/magento cache:flush
> - php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> - php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> - php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 1):

For upgrading the magento version
Navigate to Admin panel > system > web set up wizard

On this page it will ask you to choose the task among following-

1. Component Manager ( If you want to manage your packages and modules)
2. System Upgrade ( If you want to upgrade the Magento Version)
3. System Configuration ( If you want to change the system configuration)

Select the System Upgrade , it will be redirected to the page where , a Public Key and a Private Key is required.

You can get both Public Key and Private Key from your Magento Connect Account. 
Fill the appropriate keys and click Submit , it will redirect you to the magento upgrade page.

It will run the readiness check and then you have to resolve all the issues reported during readiness check and then only you will be allowed to upgrade the version.