# Upgrade Magento 2.2 to Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

Sorry, I am a newbie in Magento and I have several problems with updating Magento.
I am using this tutorial for doing so https://blog.magestore.com/upgrade-magento-2-3/
I am using community edition so I tried to follow **Upgrade Magento 2.3 manually** and **Command-line upgrade**
When I follow **Command-line upgrade** my bin/magento was simply deleted and not available anymore.
Then I clone again my project in magento and try to follow **Upgrade Magento 2.3 manually**
but then :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Zend\Mvc\Controller\LazyControllerAbstractFactory' not found in
>   /var/www/BQE/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:314
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/BQE/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/Config.php(137):
>
> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->addAbstractFactory('Zend\Mvc\Contro...')
>
> ## 1 /var/www/BQE/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php(225):
>
> Zend\ServiceManager\Config->configureServiceManager(Object(Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager))
>
> ## 2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
>
> ## 3 /var/www/BQE/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490):
>
> call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
>
> ## 4 /var/www/BQE/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(248):
>
> Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('loadModules.pos...',
>   Object(Zend\ModuleManager\Mo in
>   /var/www/BQE/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php
>   on line 314

Does someone add a similar issue? 
I mean what I do wrong ? I follow the tutorial step by step and is not working.

PS: Please in case of minus let me know why so that I can improve my post
**EDIT : my composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.0",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "msp/devtools": ">=1.2",
        "magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp": ">=1.5",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "^1.0",
        "ebizmarts/magento2-mandrill": "^3.0",
        "mirasvit/module-search-ultimate": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.10.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "amasty": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/community/"
        },
        "mirasvit-ssu2": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://27584:4NW7YLV1DJ@packages.mirasvit.com/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195050/51810 you can follow this answer. Update your magento version in that command.

Comment: Same error when I do the command php bin/magento setup:upgrade, actually this post is a shortcut of the method command-line update of the tutorial I am following

Comment: Is your "composer update" process was perfectly finished?

Comment: @Sumit their is an error I didn't seen in update I will check it, thank you

Comment: Actually with composer update I have the issue install symfony/console v2.8.38

Comment: This is the reason why the "bin/magento setup:upgrade" command gives you the error. Please share your composer.json file here to debug it further.

Comment: @Sumit ok I share up to date mesasage and composer in edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your `composer.json` file as some main content of the files were missing. You can compare both the files and check the difference.

Now follow the below steps to upgrade your Magento from 2.2.X to 2.3.2.

Update your `composer.json` with the below content.

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "msp/devtools": ">=1.2",
        "magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp": ">=1.5",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "^1.0",
        "ebizmarts/magento2-mandrill": "^3.0",
        "mirasvit/module-search-ultimate": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.10.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "amasty": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/community/"
        },
        "mirasvit-ssu2": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://27584:4NW7YLV1DJ@packages.mirasvit.com/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Remove contents from `pub/static/* generated/*` and `var/*` folder.

Run below commands to upgrade your Magento version.

```
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I hope it'll fix your issue!!!

Comment: Unfortunately is not, I have I really long message error after bin/magento setup:upgrade which was permission error, then I just chmod -R 777 and I have 3 SQL error

Comment: You've updated your composer.json file and run composer update command?

Comment: Yes first I do composer.phar update

Comment: You need to update your composer.json file available on the Magento root.

Comment: Yes this I did before, I copy the content of your composer.json instead of my composer.json, then I did composer.phar update, then I did php bin/magento setup:upgrade I had lot of permission error, then I did chmodd -R 777 on my document en then I have 3 time this error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Network is unreachable

Comment: OK, thank you for the info. It seems like the issue is with your MySQL server which is not connected. Please check details you've entered in the eav.php is correct?

Comment: ok I type locallhost instead of localhost, now it work I think, I just have this at the end of php bin/magento setup:upgrade : The directory '/var/www/mywebsite/magento/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Class Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Writer\Interceptor does not exist  
Is it meaning that all my module and extension are not available anymore ?

Comment: Great, you've got the issue now.
Just remove contents from pub/static/* generated/* and var/* folder and try it again

Comment: in commend line everything is working not other error, but then when I lauch the website I have "An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details" and in exception.log : [2019-09-02 10:37:51] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor does not exist at /var/www/mywebsite/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"} [], any idea ?

Comment: You need to recreate Interceptor by using this command "php bin/magento setup:di:compile" and removing by generated folder content.

Comment: but  "php bin/magento setup:di:compile" doesn't work MiBPHP Fatal error:  Cannot inherit previously-inherited or override constant MEDIA_GALLERY from interface Magestore\Webpos\Api\Data\Catalog\ProductInterface in /var/www/Mywebsite/magento/app/code/Magestore/Webpos/Model/Catalog/Product.php on line 32, look like an extension in a problem or something like that ?

Comment: Disable all the third-party modules in config.php and generated folder and try again.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue ?

Comment: the first one which was the topics yes, now It's a different issue with database and extension, when I put all extension at 0 I have sql error, I retsore to one but I still have error, I will drop my database and restore from backup then setupe:upload and try again di:compile

Comment: OK, great. 
It seems like the issue is with the 3rd party extension compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your `composer.json` to easily revert your upgrade in case the upgrade fails and you want to revert your upgrade.

```
$ cp composer.json composer.json.bak
```

Enable maintenance mode, so that your update will not be able to be interrupted.

```
$ bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

First, you need to remove unused packages from your `composer.json` (`--no-update` is required here, as you are not going to install it yet, just to tell `composer` that you want to add and/or remove these packages to `composer.json`).

```
$ composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
$ composer remove composer/composer magento/product-community-edition --no-update
```

Add the version `2.3.2` of `magento-product-community-edition` package to your `composer.json` (`--no-update` is required here):

```
$ composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
```

Add additional packages required by Magento 2.3.2 (still, `--no-update` is required here):

```
$ composer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.13.0 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 magento/magento-coding-standard:~1.0.0 magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:~2.3.14 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.3.1 phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.3.1 --sort-packages --no-update
```

Modify your `composer.json`'s autoload section to look like this:

```
....
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
},
....
```

If you have the Magento updater `<root_project>/update` (basically this updater is included), you also have to update it. These command will backup your old updater and install the updated one.

```
$ composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-community-edition=2.3.2 update.tmp --no-install
$ mv update update.bak
$ mv update.tmp/update update
$ rm -rf update.tmp
```

Finally, install the update.

```
$ composer update
```

Clear caches and generated content.

```
$ rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
```

Update the database schema and data.

```
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Disable maintenance mode.

```
$ bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Restart varnish (if you use one).

```
$ sudo service varnish restart
```